# How to insert random spaces in txt file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, insert, spaces

I have a file with lines of DNA in a file called 'DNASeq.txt'. I need a code to read each line and split *each* line at random places (inserting spaces) throughout the line. Each line needs to be split at different places.

EX: I have:
 AAACCCHTHTHDAFHDSAFJANFAJDSNFADKFAFJ 
    And I need something like this:
 AAA ADSF DFAFDDSAF ADF ADSF AFD AFAD

I have tried (!!!very new to python!!):

```
import random

for x in range(10):
  print(random.randint(50,250))
```

but that prints me random numbers. Is there some way to get a random number generated as like a variable?

Comment: Do you have a fixed number of splits, or is that random too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read a file line wise, write each line character-wise in a new file and insert spaces randomly:

Create demo file without spaces:

```
with open("t.txt","w") as f:
    f.write("""ASDFSFDGHJEQWRJIJG
ASDFJSDGFIJ
SADFJSDFJJDSFJIDFJGIJSRGJSDJFIDJFG
SDFJGIKDSFGOROHPTLPASDMKFGDOKRAMGO""")
```

Read and rewrite demo file:

```
import random
max_no_space = 9 # if max sequence length without space
no_space = 0
with open("t.txt","r") as f, open("n.txt","w") as w: 
    for line in f:
        for c in line:
            w.write(c)
            if random.randint(1,6) == 1 or no_space >= max_no_space:
                w.write(" ")
                no_space = 0
            else:
                no_space += 1
with open("n.txt") as k:
    print(k.read())
```

Output:

```
ASDF SFD GHJEQWRJIJG 
A SDFJ SDG FIJ
SADFJSD FJ JDSFJIDFJG I JSRGJSDJ FIDJFG
```

The pattern of spaces is random. You can influence it by settin `max_no_spaces` or remove the randomness to split after `max_no_spaces` all the time

---

Edit:

This way of writing 1 character at a time if you need to read 200+ en block is not very economic, you can do it with the same code like so:

```
with open("t.txt","w") as f:
    f.write("""ASDFSFDGHJEQWRJIJSADFJSDFJJDSFJIDFJGIJSRGJSDJFIDJFGG
ASDFJSDGFIJSADFJSDFJJDSFJIDFJGIJSRGJSDJFIDJFGSADFJSDFJJDSFJIDFJGIJK
SADFJSDFJJDSFJIDFJGIJSRGJSDJFIDJFGSADFJSDFJJDSFJIDFJGIJSRGJSDJFIDJF
SDFJGIKDSFGOROHPTLPASDMKFGDOKRAMGSADFJSDFJJDSFJIDFJGIJSRGJSDJFIDJFG""")


import random
min_no_space = 10
max_no_space = 20 # if max sequence length without space
no_space = 0
with open("t.txt","r") as f, open("n.txt","w") as w: 
    for line in f:
        for c in line:
            w.write(c)
            if no_space > min_no_space:
                if random.randint(1,6) == 1 or no_space >= max_no_space:
                    w.write(" ")
                    no_space = 0
            else:
                no_space += 1
with open("n.txt") as k:
    print(k.read())
```

Output:

```
ASDFSFDGHJEQ WRJIJSADFJSDF JJDSFJIDFJGIJ SRGJSDJFIDJFGG
 ASDFJSDGFIJSA DFJSDFJJDSFJIDF JGIJSRGJSDJFIDJ FGSADFJSDFJJ DSFJIDFJGIJK
SADFJ SDFJJDSFJIDFJG IJSRGJSDJFIDJ FGSADFJSDFJJDS FJIDFJGIJSRG JSDJFIDJF
SDFJG IKDSFGOROHPTLPASDMKFGD OKRAMGSADFJSDF JJDSFJIDFJGI JSRGJSDJFIDJFG
```

Comment: Thanks a million. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Is there a way to set the minimum sequence length without spaces? I am trying to get sequences that range from about 200-500 base pairs in length and the code is great I just need to set a minimum length before it inserts a space ( no single base pairs alone). Your help is so greatly appreciated! Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split your DNA fixed amount of times (10 in my example) here's what you could try:

```
import random

DNA = 'AAACCCHTHTHDAFHDSAFJANFAJDSNFADKFAFJ'
splitted_DNA = ''

for split_idx in sorted(random.sample(range(len(DNA)), 10)):
    splitted_DNA += DNA[len(splitted_DNA)-splitted_DNA.count(' ') :split_idx] + ' '
splitted_DNA += DNA[split_idx:]

print(splitted_DNA) # -> AAACCCHT HTH D AF HD SA F JANFAJDSNFA DK FAFJ
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your time!! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

with open('source', 'r') as in_file:
  with open('dest', 'w') as out_file:
    for line in in_file:
      newLine = ''.join(map(lambda x:x+' '*random.randint(0,1), line)).strip() + '\n'
      out_file.write(newLine)
```

Since you mentioned being new, I'll try to explain

- I'm writing the new sequences to another file for precaution. It's
  not safe to write to the file you are reading from.
- The with constructor is so that you don't need to explicitly close
  the file you opened.
- Files can be read line by line using for loop.
- ''.join() converts a list to a string.
- map() applies a function to every element of a list and returns the
  results as a new list.
- lambda is how you define a function without naming it. `lambda x:
  2*x` doubles the number you feed it.
- x + ' ' * 3 adds 3 spaces after x. random.randint(0, 1) returns
  either 1 or 0. So I'm randomly selecting if I'll add a space after
  each character or not. If the random.randint() returns 0, 0 spaces are added.

Answer (score 0):

You can toss a coin after each character whether to add space there or not.
This function takes string as input and returns output with space inserted at random places.

```
def insert_random_spaces(str):
    from random import randint
    output_string = "".join([x+randint(0,1)*" " for x in str])
    return output_string
```